# Reading file character by character and assigning value from the dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to read the protein sequence and asign charge to each amino-acid.
Sequence is written as a text (one letter to one amino-acid) in a file.

I made list where each letter gets a charge, but I am failing to read it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
charge_list = {
'G'  :   0.0,
'A'  :   0.0,
'V'  :   0.0,
'C'  :   0.0,
'P'  :   0.0,
'L'  :   0.0,
'I'  :   0.0,
'M'  :   0.0,
'W'  :   0.0,
'F'  :   0.0,
'S'  :   0.0,
'T'  :   0.0,
'Y'  :   0.0,
'N'  :   0.0,
'Q'  :   0.0,
'K'  :   1.0,
'R'  :   1.0,
'H'  :   1.0,
'D'  :  -1.0,
'E'  :  -1.0,
}

def sequence_to_charge(infile):
    file1 = open(infile, 'r')
    while True:
        char = file1.read(1)
        if not char:
            break
        print(char)
        print(charge_list[char])
    file1.close()


sequence_to_charge("test.dat")
```

test.dat looks like this
`GKDE`

2 comments:

- if I skip the `print(charge_list[char])` line, my sequence is printed, but with the 2 empty lines in the end (no idea why):

  ```
  G
  K
  D
  E
  ```
- my final goal would be to save the charge list in a file2 which looks like:
  `0 1 -1 -1`
  or

  ```
  0
  1
  -1
  -1
  ```

  (to have some kind of an array which I can work with in the next steps)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you post an exact copy of your test.dat file? I've run your code with the file contents as `GKDE` and it prints what you seem to want. Maybe you have an extra newline at the end of the file?

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. I wasn't able to reproduce the issue with the info you provided. I tried adding a newline to `test.dat` but that threw a `KeyError`. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/9cd811466facb2da1d4ae247f066aaa6) with the code that *is* working. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to read the data in your file first into a string, and then loop over the characters in the string:

```
def sequence_to_charge(infile):
    with open(infile, 'r') as file1:
        chars = file1.read()
    for char in chars:
        if char in charge_list:
            print(char, charge_list[char])

sequence_to_charge('text.txt')
```

Prints:

```
G 0.0
K 1.0
D -1.0
E -1.0
```

Comment: `for char in file1.read():` would save one more line

Comment: ;-) Little less verbose, but True.

Comment: Thanks, but I got

('G', 0.0)
('K', 1.0)
('D', -1.0)
('E', -1.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ml.py", line 40, in <module>
    sequence_to_charge('test.dat')
  File "ml.py", line 38, in sequence_to_charge
    print(char, charge_list[char])
KeyError: '\n'

Format is probably just the python vs python 3, but error I do nit understand, probably something with the new line

Comment: @shoma_pfc You have newlines in your file, just as the comment to your question suggested. Check `if char in charge_list:` before you do `charge_list[char]`.

Comment: I do not have new lines

Comment: @shoma_pfc Yes you do.

Comment: Sorry that I still do not get it, a full working solution would be appriciated :)

File is created as  echo "GKDE" > test.dat
so no new lines there...

Comment: Apart from newlines, it is save to check whether the character in the file has a an entry in the lookup dictionary. Changed my answer for that.

Comment: @shoma: if this is still not working for you, please post a realistic example of the input file. The error you receive clearly states that it is reading a newline character. Don't confuse a newline character with a blank line, just starting to write letters on the next line in the file already yields a newline character.

Comment: Thanks, it is working!

I just try to remove brackets in python 2

```
('G', 0.0)
('K', 1.0)
('D', -1.0)
('E', -1.0)
```